# How can I update the number of rows in a TableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Suppose I initially set up my number of rows as such:

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 100
}
```

If I add something to the table and call

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

How do I get the number of rows to update to 101? Can I somehow call that function again but return 101?

Comment: What is your data model behind the table?  Normally it is an array - in which case for `numberOfRowsInSection` you return `array.count`

Answer (score 10):

First I suggest you to learn MVC design pattern,this is helpful when you learn ios coding.
Then,when you use dynamic tableview, I think you should keep data source of tableveiw.

For example
In your tableviewcontroller

keep an Array to be your data source:

```
var Array = [something you want]
```

Then in

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return array.count
}
```

Then if you want to change UI,just change this array,and reload or insert/delete rows